# Let div expand to fit text, but maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a page that creates a wordcloud from the contents of an SQL table. I'm trying to figure out how to make a div that automatically resizes based on the amount of text (number of words in the cloud) it contains, but maintains its aspect ratio.

The cloud is currently contained in a div like this:

```
.container {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

As the number of words grows, I want this div to grow by both width and height, so it doesn't lose its shape.

What is the best way to go about this?

I drew the following diagram to explain what I mean:

[image: diagram]

[And here is a JSFiddle showing one output. At the moment, adding more words just expands the height of the container div without changing the width.](http://jsfiddle.net/wmn6ehbf/)

Comment: The browser has no way of knowing what the content's "shape" should be. You'd have to use line breaks or some other structure.

Comment: @isherwood guess what I'm trying to do is get the container div to fit to the divs containing the words inside it, while being restricted to a certain ratio of height to width. I'm not concerned with the exact layout of the words within the box. (They're randomly arranged.)

Comment: @EmmetOT Have you tried using `max-width` and `max-height`? The div normally will expand based on its content. The reason your container div doesn't change width is because you explicitly set it's width to 50%.

Comment: @AnthonyValera That's definitely an improvement, thanks! However the div slams up against its max width pretty quickly and then will only expand by height anyway, so I'm still trying to figure out a way to force the two dimensions to stay relative to one another up until one of them hits the max.

Comment: You will need a JavaScript/jQuery assisted solution for this, it cannot be done by CSS alone.